# trouble adding jQuery UI to Wordpress admin page

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm attempting to add a datepicker to a custom meta box in wordpress. If I enqueue the script like so

```
// add stylesheets for date picker
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_datepicker_styles');
function add_datepicker_styles() {
    global $post;
    $styleFile = get_bloginfo("template_url").'/refactored-datepicker/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css';
    if(file_exists($styleFile) && $post->post_type == 'show') {
        wp_enqueue_style("datepicker-css", $styleFile);
    }
}
// add javascript for date picker
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'add_datepicker_js');
function add_datepicker_js() {
    global $post;
    $jsFile = get_bloginfo("template_url").'/refactored-datepicker/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js';
    if(file_exists($jsFile) && $post->post_type == 'show') {
        wp_enqueue_script("datepicker-js", $jsFile);
    }
}
// add date picker init
add_action('admin_head', 'add_datepicker_init');
function add_datepicker_init() {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'show') {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#show_date').datepicker(); });</script>";
    }
}
```

I get an error that jQuery('#show_date').datepicker(); is not a function. When I check the processed source code I see that jQuery is loaded by default but the style and jQuery UI script are not loaded at all. The code attached to the admin_head hook loads fine and if I echo the script and styles in this function it works the way I want it to.

```
// add date picker init
add_action('admin_head', 'add_datepicker_init');
function add_datepicker_init() {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'show') {
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='".get_bloginfo("template_url").'/refactored-datepicker/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css'."' />";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".get_bloginfo('template_url').'/refactored-datepicker/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'."'></script>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#show_date').datepicker(); });</script>";
    }
}
```

So is it a problem with the wp_enqueue_style/script() functions or with the add_action hooks? I'm new to wordpress so I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot this. I've done a google search and everywhere I go the code looks like mine. Also if you are wondering the paths to the files are correct.

Can anyone think of a solution to my problem? Is it wrong to just echo the script and styles or should I enqueue them?

Thanks!

EDIT:

file_exists($jsFile) returns false. if I remove the conditional check for the file the code works.. But why? how else can you check for a file that exists using a url beginning with http:// as opposed to a local file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a local path for your theme, you can use `get_theme_root()`:

```
$styleFile = get_theme_root().'/refactored-datepicker/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css';
    if(file_exists($styleFile) && $post->post_type == 'show') {
```

From [php.net/file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#103436):

> this code here is in case you want to check if a file exists in
> another server:
>
> ```
> <?php function fileExists($path){
>     return (@fopen($path,"r")==true); } ?>
> ```
>
> unfortunately the file_exists can't reach remote servers, so I used
> the fopen function.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried fopen with no success and get_theme_root() returns the file path from the root directory of my shared hosting not the root of my domain pointer.

Comment: What about `get_template_directory()` instead of `get_theme_root()`? I've tried both solutions (file_exists and fopen) on an installation of WordPress and they seem to be working for me.